# HasData Equivalent in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

While I am using SQL Server as database, I can insert a record using `HasData` inside on `OnModelCreating` in the specified `DbContext` like this:

```
builder.Entity<Company>()
       .HasData(new Company {
                                Id = default(Guid).ToString(),
                                Name = "System",
                            });
```

How could I achieve the same in MongoDb?

Comment: I suppose one would match on a nominal criteria that assures there is data i.e. >0 ...or whatever is appropriate for the field type...by 'insert record' do you intend to mean insert a new document or insert a field into an existing document?

Comment: Yes I want to insert a document into MongoDb